# Как правильно: вдаль или в даль?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: "вдаль" или "в даль" и в каких случаях?

Answer (score 7):

Наречия с пространственно-временным значением надо отличать от омонимичных существительных с предлогом. Смотреть вдаль - всмотреться в даль неба. Зависимое слово  служит показателем того, что перед нами существительное. Вы, как автор высказывания, конечно, вольны сами решить, что вы имеете в виду. Но если Вы выполняете работу на оценку. советую вам все-таки обратить внимание на наличие зависимого слова (не  на возможность подставить его, а именно на наличие).

Ср. у Лопатина:

"Следует различать слитно пишущиеся наречия и совпадающие с ними в буквенном составе, но пишущиеся раздельно сочетания предлогов со словами других частей речи (существительными, прилагательными, наречиями, местоимениями). В таком различении большую роль играет контекст. Именно в контексте выявляется реальное значение и типичные синтаксические связи слов разных частей речи. Ср. следующие пары примеров: уехать насовсем (наречие, отвечает на вопрос «как?») — сослался на совсем старые данные (предлог на, относящийся к существительному данные, + наречие совсем, относящееся к прилагательному старые и образующее с ним
словосочетание); поговорить с кем-нибудь напрямую — выйти на прямую дорогу; действовать заодно с кем-нибудь — посчитать два посещения за одно; удивился, затем рассмеялся (наречие, отвечает на вопрос «когда?») — за тем домом уже поля (предлог за + местоимение тем); вначале (наречие, отвечает на вопрос «когда?») всем было интересно — в начале пути все оживлённо шутили (предлог в + существительное начало, образующее с зависимым от него словом путь словосочетание); посмотреть наверх — с обрыва на верх повозки посыпались камни; **вдали виден лес — в дали, скрытой туманом; глядеть вдаль — всматриваться в даль степей**; распространяться вглубь и вширь — вникать в глубь, в суть проблемы. В зависимости от понимания текста пишущий может выбрать и слитное, и раздельное написание в таких, например, случаях: погрузиться вглубь (в глубь) океана, зайти вглубь (в глубь) леса, гнездо наверху (на верху) дерева".

Добавляю. У Розенталя все однозначно:

*7. Пишутся слитно наречия с пространственным и временным значением, имеющие в своем составе существительные верх, низ, перед, зад, высь, даль, глубь, ширь, начало, конец, век. Например: вверх, вверху, доверху, кверху, наверх, вниз, внизу, книзу, снизу, вперед, назад, ввысь, вдаль, вдали, вглубь, вширь, вначале, сначала, вконец, наконец, ввек, довеку, навек, навеки.
Примечание 1. **Возможность вставки** определяющего слова (ср.: вверх — в самый верх) **не влечет за собой раздельного их написания**. Раздельно эти слова пишутся только при наличии в самом предложении пояснительного слова к указанным существительным или по смыслу контекста, например: к низу платья, в глубь океана, в даль туманную, в начале осени, во веки веков, на веки вечные, повторить урок с начала (т. е. «от начала», а не «сперва»). Ср.: Науку изучают с азов, дружбу берегут с начала (пословица). Но: Нужно начать все сначала (в значении «заново, опять, еще раз»).*

Примеры без пояснительного слова достаточно прозрачны.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от ситуации. Уйти куда — вдаль. Уйти во что — в голубую даль. То есть, когда речь о какой-то конкретной дали, то раздельно. Если указывается общее направление, то это наречие и пишется слитно. Собственно, так, как и с наречиями "вверх", "вниз", "вправо", "влево".

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от части речи: если существительное, то раздельно; если наречие, то слитно. Главное - не перепутать части речи.

Answer (score 2):

По сути - присоединяюсь к Ларf.
Но есть изрядная ложка дегтя в этой истории со слитным-раздельным написанием. Везде говорят, что надо различать наречие и существительноt с предлогом. Но ни Лопатин, ни кто-либо ещё не сообщают, как это сделать в практической ситуации.

В огромном числе случаев возможно двоякое написание - и выбор зависит от контекста, смысла и - самое неприятное - даже воли автора. Наверняка можно сказать только то, что есть согласованные, зависимые слова или обособляемые обороты (обычно в поэтической или возвышенной речи: *"в даль далекую", "в даль веков", "в даль, в глубь и в ширь"* -  и т.д.), то это существительное с предлогом и написание, таким образом, раздельное. Но если там наречие и слитное написание, то почти всегда возможна грамматически непротиворечивая замена на существительное с предлогом.  *"Я смотрел в(?)даль. В(?)дали был только туман"*. Увы...
Или кто-то знает формальное правило на этот счет?

Comment: Формальный признак - наличие зависимого слова. У РОзенталя всегда было однозначно. (Добавила в ответ). В школе однозначно до сих пор. Если бы не заглянула в справочник Лопатина, не написала бы о возможности выбора. Хотя я с ним согласна. ПОлучается раньше правило было четче? А с другой стороны, меня по-прежнему интересует нормативность справочника Лопатина.